# DJANGO Get First, Second and Third most found Value in a Model

Tags: django

I got a Dashboard model that is filled by a schduled Job.

**dashboard model**

```
class dashboard(models.Model):
    topvul1=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    topvul2=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    topvul3=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to show the most found, second most found and third most found `VID` from the `clientvul` model. And fill it once per Day to my `dashboard` model.

**clientvul model**

```
class clientvul(models.Model):
    
    client= models.ForeignKey(client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vid=models.ForeignKey(vul, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    path=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    product=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    isactive=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
               fields=['client', 'VID'], name='unique_migration_host_combination' # legt client und VID als Primarykey fest
            )
        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of `clientvul`s for each `vul` and then order and return the first three:

```
from django.db.models import Count

vul.objects.alias(
    num_client=Count('clientvul_set')
).order_by('-num_client')[:3]
```

there is no need to make a model for this. Unless we are talking about billions of records, such queries run in milliseconds, and are more robust since it will also change the order in case a `clientvul` is removed for example.

Comment: @xMonkey1337: yeah, but unless we are talking about billions of records, such queries often are not that expensive: the database uses an index on `FOREIGN KEY`s, and thus often can determine the number of records linked to a certain item quite fast.

Comment: Where should I store the Output so I can display deltas (like 13 less then last week)